# localtime_r returns null for large number

Tags: c++

1. I have a large value of seconds.and i want to convert the seconds into struct tm but when i use localtime_r it returns null for large value.
2. **is there any way to convert large value of seconds into struct tm**

or

3. **what is the largest value I can pass to localtime_r function so that it wont return NULL?**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <map>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  time_t seconds= 9223372036854775807; 
  struct tm timeResult;
  struct tm *endTimeTm = localtime_r(&seconds, &timeResult);
  if (!endTimeTm)cout<<"null";
  else cout<<"not null";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But that would be about year 292,278,994,000. That is about 21 times the age of the universe in the future! Are you sure you really want to know the month and day of week of that `tm`?

Comment: what is largest value of seconds I can pass to localtime_r function so that it wont return null?

Comment: Well, I guess that is implementation dependent. Just for fun, in my linux machine, using the `date` tool that I assume uses this very same call, and doing a binary search, the maximum value is `67768036191673199`, that corresponds to the 23:59:59 of December 31st of year 2147485547. Interestingly this year is exactly `1900 + 0x7fffffff`.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any way to convert large value of seconds into struct tm

Even with 64-bit `time_t`, 9223372036854775807 certainly out of range of what `localtime_r()` can convert.  `.tm_year` member would have too large a value - outside `int` range.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your input number is just too huge. When looking at the [Docs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime_r) you can see that `localtime_r` returns `NULL` in case of an error. What error you might guess?
Having a look at the `struct *tm` (you can have a look at it in the spec) saves the years (which is the "largest" time unit) as an integer, which is 32bit in size. But the time you are requesting requires log2(9223372036854775807 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 356)
= 39bit, which your regular integer can't support.

Short answer: your `time_t` integer is just too big.